# facebook login / log out

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, logout

I have created a facebook login which is working fine. When the user is logged in he gets to proceed to the next activity. When he press the home button, and then returns to the app, the app starts with FacebookLogin activity, and the Facebook logOut button appears with nothing else on the screen. The only option is to logout and login again.

I want the user to be able to return to the app without having to logout, and then login again.

Here is my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook_login);
            loginbutton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_bn);
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            loginbutton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new 
            FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FacebookLoginActivity.this, 
            ModeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {


        }


        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }

    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first activity is of Facebook login so every time app starts it will show that. If user is not logged in it will show login button otherwise logout button. You can check if user is logged in or not then you can navigate to ModeActivity